# nginx reverse proxy based on jsonrpc method

Tags: nginx

So we have an RPC endpoint that queries an application which is setup behind nginx (as a reverse proxy)

```
Internet sending POST JSON RPC -> Nginx at :443 ... proxies to -> Web Application at :8080
```

The application accepts jsonrpc POST requests coming from the internet, e.g.

```
{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "subtract", "params": {"subtrahend": 23, "minuend": 42}, "id": 3}
```

Nginx is used to terminate SSL, do basic load-balancing and add required headers.

A vast majority of requests coming to the RPC endpoint from the internet are the same and the response changes relatively rarely, so we'd like to use a kind of cache to lower the load on the application.

Is it possible to configure nginx to read the body of jsonrpc POST request, extract the value of `"method"` and route the request based on that value either to application or to the caching service?

```
Internet sending POST JSON RPC -> Nginx at :443 reads "method" from POST body ...
    -> if method == "getCounter" ... proxies to -> Caching service                                                                      
    -> if method != "getCounter" ... proxies to -> Application at :8080
```

Comment: have you found the answer to share it? thanks.